# Resource bundle class in java throwing excetion while reading the properties file

Tags: java, servlets, properties, resourcebundle

I am trying to read a properties file using a resource bundle class in java, but it is giving me a exception saying that

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name jira, locale en_US
```

This is how i am coding in java

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("jira");
```

This is my project structure
[image]

What is that missing? I have read through the documentation and it says that no need to give any absolute path as the Resource bundle handles that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourceBundles` are read from the classpath. `WEB-INF/conf` is not on the classpath for web applications. Try placing the property file in `WEB-INF/classes`.

From the above image it appears you are using Maven to build the project. In that case the property file can be moved into `src/main/resources` folder to be copied into `classes` during the Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of your bundle file. File name should begins with the base name LabelsBundle and ends with the .properties suffix. Since you are trying to load file intended for your default Locale, the base name is followed by the language code (en_US).

`jire_en_US.properties`

should be the file name of your bundle file instead of just

`jira.properties`